# Helical wavefronts of vortex beams

Tags: optics

Vortex beams are characterized by an azimuthal angle phase dependence, basically $e^{i l\phi}$. Why is this azimuthal angle phase dependence crucial and will I get a helix if I were to plot the surface of constant phase for Laguerre Gaussian beams?

NB: I have edited the question because of a confusion.

Comment: Is $\phi$ the azimuthal angle or the phase? You seem to be using it for both quantities.

Comment: phi is the azimuthal angle. I'm just drawing parallels with a plane wave. Can you point which part of the question suggests I've used it for both?

Comment: Then constant phase does not necessarily mean constant azimuthal angle, because the point of zero phase can be different in different cross-sections. What you're suggesting would lead to a constant electric field magnitude for all points along the axis of propagation, which wouldn't be a propagating wave.

Comment: I didn't get your point there. Can you please elaborate? Alternatively, can you give an explanation of why Lagurre-Gaussian beams have helical wavefronts, if possible with the equation of the constant phase surface that suggests so?

Comment: The beam must be a propagating wave, and propagating waves cannot have constant phase along the axis of propagation.

Comment: I might've got your point there and there is a z-dependence on the overall phase after checking it again. The phi dependence seems crucial for helical beams though. Can you give an explanation of why this azimuthal dependence is crucial for the helical wavefronts to exist? And if I were to really plot a surface contour of the phase will I get a helix?  I'll edit my question to avoid confusion.

Comment: Without azimuthal dependence of the phase (i.e. if the phase only changes along the direction of propagation), you would just have a plane wave.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't take into account the z-dependence of the phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the wave propagates in the $z$ direction and $\Phi(z,r, \phi,t)$ is the phase of the wave
$$
A(r)e^{i\Phi(z,r, \phi,t)}= 
A(r)e^{ikz -i\omega t+il\phi},
$$
then the surfaces of constant $\Phi$, are indeed helical.